# What face do I need to adjust to remove the gutters at the edges of my windows?

Tags: faces, themes

This is not urgent, but just wondering if an Emacs user could let me know which face I need to adjust to remove the faint gutters at the edge of my windows?

I am using GUI `GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 X86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0` (installed via Homebrew if that makes a difference) and using `molokai` theme installed via `color-theme` package

[image: These buffers here]

Thank you

Comment: Some people remove the fringes entirely; however, others like the adjustable fringe width and either make the color match the background or contrast that color against the background.  I like to display bitmaps in the fringe, so I need a certain minimum width.

Comment: I have been using Emacs for about 6 months and only just now using the GUI. I think I like it with the two matching. Contrasting is a bit annoying for my eyes. Thank you for the heads up though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The face is called...`fringe`.

You can see all currently defined faces using `M-x list-faces-display`.

So just `M-x customize-face fringe`.

Comment: Thank you. That's great. All adjusted now, and was able to change my cursor too while I was at it :)

Comment: I should add, for anyone searching in the future, I added the following to my `init` files and it solved it perfectly for the theme I'm currently using:

`(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "#1B1D1E")`